# How to get access to ResourceData[...]

Tags: dataset, curated-data, resourceobject

I use:

```
Association[Normal[ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"][All, {#AdministrativeDivision, #Country} -> #ConfirmedCases &]]]
```

I get the following errors:

```
Transpose::nmtx: The first two levels of {$Failed} cannot be transposed.
Set::shape: Lists {DataResource`Private`locations,DataResource`Private`formats} and Transpose[{$Failed}] are not the same shape.
Import::chtype: First argument DataResource`Private`locations is not a         valid file, directory, or URL specification.
```

I have MMA version 11.3

Can someone tell me the reasons for the errors?

**EDIT 1**

Can someone try the above one-line `code` in both MMA 11.3 and MMA 12.2? The result of this trial will be the answer to my question.

**EDIT 2**

When I try

```
Import["https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath/json/", "JSON"]
```

I receive the following error:

```
FetchURL::conopen: The connection to URL https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath/json/ cannot be opened. 
If the URL is correct, you might need to configure your firewall program, or you might need to set a proxy in the Internet connectivity tab of the Preferences dialog (or by calling SetInternetProxy).
For HTTPS connections, you might need to inspect the authenticity of the server's SSL certificate and choose to accept it.
```

Comment: It works on MMA 12.2.0. Since it requires access to off site curated data, maybe it was a temporary malfunction.

Comment: @MarcoB: I am suspicious that it does not work with MMA 11.3. I do not think it is about temporary malfunctioning because I have been trying this for about a week and you just showed that it works on your computer. I think this is something to do with MMA 11.3.

Comment: I no longer have 11.3 installed, but I tried it on 12.0 on my laptop and had the same results (the 12.2 was run on the cloud). I don't know that it is version-dependent as much as cloud vs. desktop dependent. The basic call to `ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19", "WorldCountries"]` fails as you showed on my laptop with version 12.0 as well.

Comment: Similarly, `ResourceData["Genetic Sequences for the SARS-CoV-2 Coronavirus"]` also fails in the same way. Clearly there is a problem with that data set. Have you considered going straight to the source instead? The underlying data from Johns Hopkins University should be available on GitHub: https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

Comment: @MarcoB: I visited the JHU link you suggested but it is a daunting task to get the data in the format readily available for use. Maybe MMA experts need to do something about the problem MMA 11.3 has. Thank you again.

Comment: In version 11.3.0 (windows 10-64b) `rd = ResourceData["Epidemic Data for Novel Coronavirus COVID-19"]` works fine (it gives a dataset with a note that "..an update is available for ...").  The query `rd[All, {#AdministrativeDivision, #Country} -> #ConfirmedCases &]` also works fine. `Normal[rd[
  All, {#AdministrativeDivision, #Country} -> #ConfirmedCases &]]` takes a long time but does return what is expected. Similarly for `Association@
 Normal[rd[ All, {#AdministrativeDivision, #Country} -> #ConfirmedCases &]]`.

Comment: @kglr: Thanks for trying it with different versions. It seems that the `code` in the question is working fine with version 11.3. But still, I do not know why my computer returns the errors given in the question. Now I will switch off/on my computer to see if anything changes.

Comment: @kglr: I turned off/on my computer and still the same errors prevail. All the `codes` you tested above do not work with my computer. The fact that @MarcoB also receives similar errors makes me think that the dataset may be of the format my computer has a problem with. I hope more people will test it with different versions/machines. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When I run this code on mma v12, I get a massive list of data.

```
thing = Import["https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/nationalcasedeath/json/", "JSON"];

thing[[;;1]]

{{"country" -> "Afghanistan", "country_code" -> "AFG", "continent" -> "Asia", "population" -> 38928341, "indicator" -> "cases", "weekly_count" -> 0, "year_week" -> "2020-01", "cumulative_count" -> 0, "source" -> "Epidemic intelligence, national weekly data"}}

Length@thing
(*22852*)
```

So the errors that you're getting are very much internet errors and or machine related things and not something wrong with your code.

Your other code gives me the same errors aswell in all versions of MMA I have, which leads me to believe there is a bug of some kind, or that the Resource objects are somehow broken on Wolframs side. Corona analysis programs I have used over the past year are now broken as of today. Contact Wolfram about this, or link to this thread.

```
ResourceData[ro]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to declare a bug to Wolfram?

Comment: @TugrulTemel i’d just write an email to support, quick explanation and a link to this thread

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to declare this problem to WL. I appreciate it much.

Comment: @Tugrul Temel you should report this also.

Comment: @CA Trevillian: I will do it now.

Comment: @morbo: I received an answer from MMA service about access to COVID data. Please see my last question I posted today where I explained the way to access the data. Now it works for me even with MMA 11.3. the problem was that MMA depository had a problem, not users.

Answer (score 1):

Six weeks on from the OP, and I'm getting the same problem with my calls to the data repository. E.g. for Magna Carta, see below...

[image]

Similarly, the examples in help for `ResourceData` and `ResourceObject` that use `"Gettysburg Address"` don't work. The example using `"Guinea Pig Tooth Growth Sample Data"` does work.

ETA. If I get `ro=ResourceObject["Magna Carta"]`, and then use `elems=ro["ContentElements"]`, it returns `{"Author", "Content", "FormattedText", "FullTitle", "Language", "Lines", "NotebookExpression", "Title", "Words"}`. Of these I can retrieve, via `ResourceData[ro,#]&/@elems`, valid data for `"Author", "FullTitle", "Language", "Title"`, and I get `Null` for `"FormattedText"` (i.e. `"FormattedText"` is not recognised as a content element, despite being listed as one) and failures for everything else (the actual useful data). Similarly, with the Guinea Pig Tooth Growth data, the example given in help works and some other data elements, e.g. the study author, are available, but actual content returns the usual `$Failed`.

It looks as though the data repository might be pretty broken.

Comment: Please report this to [Wolfram technical support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/?topic=Feedback).

Comment: I have now found that this problem does not occur in version 12.2. It seems to be a problem with Version 12.0 on Windows 7.